# using indexof method i can find the value in string

Tags: javascript

```
var str  = "java javascript 'core php' 'core java' css";
str.split(' ');
```

This give the result as array `['java' ,'javascript', 'core', 'php', 'core', 'java','css']`

but i want result `['java', 'java' ,'javascript', 'core php', 'core java', css]`
single quoted element as one string in javascript

Comment: what does the title have to do with the question?

Comment: your result array is actually different than you posted. Its something like `['java' ,'javascript', '\'core', 'php\'', '\'core', 'java\'','css']` which is pretty obvious. I wonder what the source of your data is but it is very unhandy if you have to split this string into a nice array

Comment: plz explain a bit more

Comment: What's the logic in getting the first two being `java` items when there is only one before `javascript` in the string?

Comment: The question is how do I take a string `"java javascript 'core php' 'core java' css"` and turn it into an array `['java' ,'javascript', 'core php', 'core java', `css`]`

Comment: @epascarello Though OP say they want two `java` as the first two items...?

Comment: I am willing to bet it was a typo @LGSon....

Comment: @epascarello Me too, hence my first comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly not the most beautiful way but it's work.

```js
var str  = "java javascript 'core php' 'core java' css";
var resu = [];
var index = 0;
var coteOpen = false;
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) 
{
 if(str.charAt(i) == '\'')
 {
  coteOpen = !coteOpen;
 }
 else if(str.charAt(i) == ' ' && !coteOpen)
 {
  index++
 }
 else
 {
    if(resu[index] == null)
      resu[index] = str.charAt(i)
    else
      resu[index] += str.charAt(i)
 }
}

console.log(resu);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kvasir provided an answer, but in case you don't want to iterate through the whole string, letter-by-letter, here is another option:

```
let str  = "java javascript 'core php' 'core java' css"
let index = 0

do {
  index = str.indexOf('\'', index)
  if (index != -1) {
    let inStep = index
    let outStep = str.indexOf('\'',index+1)
    if (outStep != -1) {
      index = outStep
      let string = str.substring(inStep, outStep+1)
      str = str.replace(string, string.replace(/\'/g, '').replace(/ /g, '-'))
    } else break
  }
} while (str.indexOf('\'',index+1) != -1)

let result = str.split(' ').map(i => i.replace(/-/g,' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well since, as Flame mentions, the \' character is included in the words split out, it might be even easier to loop through the array after the split and look for that character:

```
var stri = "wat you say 'there is' no peace in 'the world'";
var wrds = stri.split(' ');
var newwrds = [];
var i,j;
for (i=0, j=0;i<wrds.length;i++){
    if (wrds[i].charAt(0) == '\''){
        newwrds[j] = wrds[i].slice(1) + " " + wrds[i+1].slice(0,-1);
        i++;
        j++;
    } else {
        newwrds[j] = wrds[i];
        j++;
    }

}
```

output is `['what', 'you', 'say', 'there is', 'no', 'peace', 'in', 'the world']`

Can add a do..while loop to allow for longer than 2-word items if needed.